# What is the difference between will have and have

Tags: future-tense

> He will have a girlfriend

vs.

> He has a girlfriend.

*Will have* is for future, – but *will have* can also be used as a guess....no?

Answer (score 1):

If you are making a prediction (as opposed to an inevitable declaration), it’s normally customary to preface the remark with something like, “I guess” or “I predict”:

> *I think he will have a girlfriend*.

However, there may be times when this gets omitted for the sake of brevity, particularly when context makes it obvious you are guessing with confidence, as opposed to stating some certainty:

> Who will win tomorrow’s match?
>   *Tottingham will win tomorrow*.

Comment: We can alternatively say it this way. I think he must have a girlfriend. Right?

Comment: I would interpret “I think he will have a girlfriend” as meaning he doesn’t have a girlfriend now but he will in the future. “I think he must have a girlfriend,” on the other hand, would mean you are confident he has a girlfriend now.

Answer (score 0):

The normal usage of will is to talk about the future.

For example:

> I will go the the market tomorrow.

Tomorrow is a future date, thus we use **will** to express the future.
Note that **"will"** is often abbreviated to **'ll**.

There are several ways we use will, such as talking about the future, making decisions, making promises, offers, requests and threats, or like the one you mean here, to make predictions.

In here, I will only introduce the meaning of making predictions. If you have any doubt on the other usages, you can tell me in the comments.

### To make predictions

We also use "will" to talk about what we think will happen in the future.

For example:

> I think it'll rain tonight.
> I'm sure he'll be a successful lawyer one day.

But be careful, for "negative" predictions, make the "think" negative, not the "will":

> I don't think it'll rain tonight. (**Not** "I think it won't rain tonight.)

## Attribution

https://english-at-home.com/grammar-how-to-use-will/